# Stack divs on top of each other in 2 rows without whitespace

Tags: css, html

I really need your help on this one:

Right now I have divs just on top of each other, filled dynamically with diverse contents so the heights are changing.

What I want to do now is to place them in 2 rows. With a fixed width and "float:left" this kinda works already.

My english is not the very best so pls take a look at my example picture first:

**[image: This is how it looks like right now!]**

As you can see there is this whitespace because of the third div which doesn't start right beneath the first div because of div number 2 which CAN BE higher as the first div.

I now wonder if there is a possibility to automatically position those divs higher so that there is no whitespace (they always should start right beneath the picture which is above wouth the whitespace, left or right).

LIKE THIS:

**[image: It should look like this!]**

I hope you kinda understand what I mean :D Thanks in advance for replys!

EDIT:
Code-Example:

```
<div id="content">
<div class="xyz">BLABLA</div>
<div class="xyz">BLABLA<br>morebla!<br>EVEN MORE BLA</div>
<div class="xyz">BLABLA</div>
</div>
<style>
#content {
width: 648px;
}
.xyz {
width: 303px;
float: left;
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Remeber, heights are always different!

Comment: Where is your html and css?

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: added (even more) code example

Answer (score 2):

jQuery [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) makes your life a lot easier.. don't reinvent the wheel, especially when you're facing a classic css problem.

Comment: that should do it! Thanks for the answer, i will try it!

Comment: Not working for me right now, i'm gonna test it out a bit more and will post again here if I know more

Comment: if something specific is not working, you can probably update your question with it so that we can help

Answer (score 0):

this will do it...

```
   <div id="content">
    <div class="column1" id="left">
     <div id="div1">...</div>
     <div id="div3">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column2" id="left">
     <div id="div2">...</div>
     <div id="div4">...</div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Then just style column2 styles by defining widht values in your css.

Thanks,

@leo.

Comment: This is hard to code because as I mentioned the content is dynamic. But thanks.